# How can I draw a rectangle from the points I want, using ROI?

Tags: numpy, opencv, roi

Hello I am beginner in OpenCv.
I have a maze image. I wrote maze solver code. I need to get the photo like the picture for this code to work.
I want to choose the contours of the white area using ROI but I could not

When I try the ROI method I get a smooth rectangle with a black area selected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty5BX.png  -----> this is my code result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7zuJ.png   --------> I want to this result

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#import image
image = cv2.imread('rt4.png')

#grayscaleqq
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
#qcv2.waitKey(0)

#binary
#ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
threshold = 150
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.namedWindow('second', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('second', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#dilation
kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.namedWindow('dilated', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('dilated', img_dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()




#find contours
im2,ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), 
cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


#sort contours
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr) 
[0])

list = []

for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
# Get bounding box
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)

# Getting ROI
roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

a = w-x
b = h-y
list.append((a,b,x,y,w,h))


# show ROI
#cv2.imshow('segment no:'+str(i),roi)
cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),( x + w, y + h ),(0,255,0),2)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

if w > 15 and h > 15:
    cv2.imwrite('home/Desktop/output/{}.png'.format(i), roi)

cv2.namedWindow('marked areas', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('marked areas',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()




gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)

#result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)


image[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]

cv2.imshow('dst',image)
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

list.sort()
print(list[len(list)-1])
```

Comment: If you threshold the image and findContours on it, then drawContours, you should get the second one.

Comment: Can you explain a little more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood your question earlier. So, I'm rewriting.

As @Silencer has already stated, you could use the drawContours method. You can do it as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#import image
im = cv2.imread('Maze2.png')
gaus = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (5, 5), 1)
# mask1 = cv2.dilate(gaus, np.ones((15, 15), np.uint8, 3))
mask2 = cv2.erode(gaus, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8, 1))
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(mask2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

maxArea1=0
maxI1=0

for i in range(len(contours)):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    epsilon = 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(contours[i], True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[i], epsilon, True)
    if area > maxArea1 :
        maxArea1 = area

print(maxArea1)
print(maxI1)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, maxI1, (0,255,255), 3)

cv2.imshow("yay",im)
cv2.imshow("gray",imgray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I used it on the following image: [image]
And I got the right answer. You can add additional filters, or you could decrease the area using an ROI, to decrese the discrepancy, but it wasn't required

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your help but I can not use cv2.selectROI because 
code automatically selected rectangle

Comment: My fault! I didn't understand the question properly. I will update my answer in sometime.. Apologies!

Comment: my bad english, sorry :(

Comment: thanks for your help, I have quastion. I need full white contours. Your code gives me a little outside of the white  is drawing the frame

Comment: I figured out the problem, just run the erosion on `gaus` rather than on `mask1`, i.e. don't perform dilation at all. It works perfectly now. Run it and let me know if it works :)

Comment: worked perfectly ! Thank you. I have one more question :)
how can i crop the detected area and rotate it.

Comment: I searched a lot, there is no documentation on cutting out slant rectangles, but look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355175/cut-out-a-slant-rectangle-from-an-image-python3, might get some answers.Answer if you get to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to just draw a slanted rectangle would be to use `cv2.polylines`. Based on your result, I'm assuming you have the coordinates of the vertices of the area already, lets call them [x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3], [x4,y4]. The polylines function draws a line from vertex to vertex to create a closed polygon.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

#List coordinates of vertices as an array
pts = np.array([[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4]], np.int32)
pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))

#Draw lines from vertex to vertex
cv2.polylines(image, [pts], True, (255,0,0))
```

Comment: hi, First of all thank you for your reply. 
I do not have corner points. I just have ROI rectangle points and I do not know  how to get the corner points. I am a beginner opencv. Do you know how to get ?